# spring-data-cosmosdb: Limit the result

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use Azure cosmosDB Java API . I would like to fetch the results pagewise. For example: we can pass Pageable instance in Spring Data JPA and fetch , lets say 10, items at a time. I did not find any reference to how we can achieve this with Spring-data-cosmosdb.
I could not use @Query("") annotation too with this plugin. SO I am not sure how I can achieve pagination.

Any help is much appreciated.

regards,

Venky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to build something around the exposed `continuation token` which is represented in the `FeedResponse`.

```
    FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions();
    queryOptions.setPageSize(10);
    queryOptions.setRequestContinuation("continuation token from previous request");

    FeedResponse<Document> queryResults = this.client.queryDocuments(collectionLink,
            "SELECT * FROM Family WHERE Family.lastName = 'Andersen'", queryOptions);
    string token = queryResults.getResponseContinuation()
```

[This is an example of how you can do this in the C# SDK.](https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/08/19/paging-through-query-results-in-azure-documentdb/) I don't see a way to do the exact same thing in Java though, so you will probably need to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to accomplish this type of pagination in CosmosDb (or in most/any NoSQL database for that matter) as skip/take isn't really a supported query pattern.

The more common pattern is keep a reference to the last item seen on the client side in the form of a `continuation token` which can be sent back to the server on subsequent requests. For example, user requests the first 10 items and gets the result set back. The identifier of the 10th item is `asdfb1231`. The query to get the second "page" would include this value so that the server side can continue the query from this offset.

This has been written about extensively in other places. One of my favorite articles on the topic was written by the brilliant Yan Cui https://hackernoon.com/guys-were-doing-pagination-wrong-f6c18a91b232 which I would highly recommend reading.